# i'm adapting some code and I changed some functions to system calls but now I am getting some errors which are confusing me

Tags: c++, linux

This is the error I get:
[image]

These are the includes I needed.

```
#include "cache_handle.h"
#include <sys/stat.h>
#include <fcntl.h>
#include <unistd.h>
```

//http://www.phim.unibe.ch/comp_doc/c_manual/C/SYNTAX/struct.html
//http://vergil.chemistry.gatech.edu/resources/programming/c-tutorial/structs.html

I have changed the `fopen`, `fclose` and `fread` functions and replaced them with system calls `read`, `open` and `close` but now I have some errors which I do not understand.

```
int bufferCache_refill(bufferCacheStruct* buff){
  //Refills a buffer-cache
  //Only works when completely used buffer-cache
  if(buff->alongBufferCache!=buff->bufferCacheLength)
    return 0;
  else{
    buff->alongBufferCache=0;
    **int len=read(buff->file, buff->bufferCache, buff->bufferCacheLength);**
    //If we didn't fill the cache, fill up with EOF
    if(len<buff->bufferCacheLength)
      for(int i=len;i<buff->bufferCacheLength;i++)  
    buff->bufferCache[i]=EOF;  //Accessing like an array!
    return len;
  }
}

void file_close(bufferCacheStruct* buff){
  free(buff->bufferCache);
  **close(buff->file);**
}

bufferCacheStruct* file_open(char * filename, int bufferCacheSize){
  //Info on malloc
  //http://www.space.unibe.ch/comp_doc/c_manual/C/FUNCTIONS/malloc.html
  int f;
    if ((f = open(const char *filename, int oflag)) == -1){ // <---- here
    fprintf(stderr, "Cannot open %s\n", filename);
    return 0;
  }

  bufferCacheStruct* initBufferCache=(bufferCacheStruct*)malloc(sizeof(bufferCacheStruct));
  initBufferCache->file=f;
  initBufferCache->bufferCacheLength=bufferCacheSize;
  initBufferCache->alongBufferCache=bufferCacheSize; //Start off with no characters, so refill will work as expected
  initBufferCache->bufferCache=(char*)malloc(sizeof(char)*bufferCacheSize);

  bufferCache_refill(initBufferCache);
  return initBufferCache;
}

//------------------------------------------------------------------
char return_character(bufferCacheStruct* buff)
{
    bufferCache_refill(buff);//this refils when the buffer cache has came to an end. 
    return buff->bufferCache[buff->alongBufferCache++];//this is the return function to return the following character/text. 
}
//return EOF; // this is just so the compile works...
```

MY ERROR MESSAGE:

```
cache_handle.c: In function ‘file_open’:
cache_handle.c:40:17: error: expected expression before ‘const’
    if ((f = open(const char *filename, int oflag)) == -1){
                  ^~~~~ 
cache_handle.c:40:12: error: too few arguments to function ‘open’
    if ((f = open(const char *filename, int oflag)) == -1){
             ^~~~ 
In file included from cache_handle.c:3:0: 
/usr/include/fcntl.h:157:12: note: declared here 
 extern int open (const char *__file, int __oflag, ...) __nonnull ((1));
            ^~~~ 
<builtin>: recipe for target 'cache_handle.o' failed 
make: *** [cache_handle.o] Error 1
```

Comment: please include the error message in the question. Don't use images for things that you can post as text.

Comment: Thats not how you call a function: `open(const char *filename, int oflag)` what is this line supposed to mean?

Comment: btw you cannot use `**` in code to make it bold.

Comment: I just a added ** now to show the parts I changed.

Comment: @idclev463035818 I used linux man page and that is what it said about using system call open.

Answer (score 2):

The man page is describing the types you should use when you call `open`, it does not mean that you have to literally include those types when you make the call.

So

```
if ((f = open(const char *filename, int oflag)) == -1){
```

should be something like

```
if ((f = open(filename, O_RDONLY)) == -1){
```

Just like any other function call in fact.

Comment: Oh thank you I will look into this. Should this change, solve any of my errors? @john

Comment: @User1986 It will certainly fix the error you quoted `cache_handle.c:40:17: error: expected expression before ‘const’`.

Comment: Thank you John for your support